# Form ((using Formik and Yup)) in react isn't handling valid inputs properly, instead it is reading them as invalid inputs or as if the filed is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

Please find the codesandbox  link attached below,
The main issue with the code is that the form isn't handling inputs properly.
If the value of the input is valid, it constantly reads it as if there is no input to begin with.
The form is done using Formik and validation on Yup.

https://codesandbox.io/s/create-customer-form-using-formik-and-yup-zx7m3v

Comment: use formik `setFieldValue` instead of your custom `updateCreateFormField`.

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void

Comment: @justin Could you provide an example on how to do so? thanks again